# C compiler warning error

Tags: c

A simple program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
char b='a';
printf("%s \n", b);
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:4:1: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("%s \n", b);
 ^
```

But the second arg is `char` not `int`.

Is this a wrong warning by the compiler, or something else I am missing?

Comment: The compiler warning is correct. "The Second arg is Char" **but** '%s' expects a `char *`.

Comment: In C, `char` is an integral type. It's not the same as `int`, but the difference is only in the details because it can certainly be used just like an `int`: `char c = 'a' + 3;`.

Comment: For all practical purposes and intents, compilers are never wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is certainly correct to warn about the call. `printf` with a `"%s"` specifier requires an argument of type `char*` (which must point to a string), and the argument you pass is not of that type.

As for why the warning message refers to `int` rather than `char`, it's because `printf` is a *variadic* function. The first parameter, the format string, is declared to be of type `const char*`, but the following arguments are specified only as `, ...`. In this special case, arguments of integer types narrower than `int` are *promoted* to `int` or to `unsigned int`. So even though the expression `b` is of type `char`, the actual argument that's passed to `printf` is of type `int`; specifically, it's the result of converting the value of `b` from `char` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is accurate, though the reasons are modestly obscure.

The declaration of `printf()` is:

```
int printf(const char *restrict format, ...);
```

The `const` and `restrict` keywords aren't important for this discussion.  What is important is the ellipsis, `...`.  When arguments are passed to a function with a variable argument list (a *variadic* function), they undergo 'default argument conversions'.  Integer types shorter than `int` (`short` and `char` in their various forms) are promoted to `int`, and `float` values are promoted to `double`.  Thus, the value of `b` is converted to `int` by the rules for calling a variadic functions.

The `"%s"` format expects to be given a pointer to a null-terminated character string.  The variable `b` is a single `char`, not a string.  Consequently, the compiler is correctly warning you that you will not get good results from running the program.

In this context, using a format such as `%c` (to print a character) or `%d` (to print a decimal integer) is probably best:

```
printf("%c\n", b);
```

---

As a general rule, at this stage in your C programming career, you should assume the compiler is right and that you're wrong.  Remember, the C compiler knows a lot more about C than you do.  This isn't to say that there are never bugs in compilers.  However, the chances of you finding one are slim.  Until you know enough about C (maybe in five to ten years time), then you should assume the compiler is right, you're wrong, and work out (a) what the compiler means and (b) how to fix it.

It was not always thus.  Thirty years ago, bad compilers existed because the best were not all that much better.  It was possible to find bugs in those compilers.  There has, however, been a serious winnowing and few incompetent compilers are left on the market.  One area where you can sometimes find compilers with surprising limitations (occasionally tantamount to bugs) is in specialized embedded systems for obscure chips.  However, in mainstream o/s for desktops and servers (and tablets and smart phones), you're unlikely to come across a seriously defective compiler.

---

#### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.5.2.2 Function calls

> ¶6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a
>   prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that
>   have type `float` are promoted to `double`. These are called the *default argument
>   promotions*. If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the
>   behavior is undefined. If the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype, and
>   either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (`, ...`) or the types of the arguments after
>   promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined.
>   If the function is defined with a type that does not include a prototype, and the types of
>   the arguments after promotion are not compatible with those of the parameters after
>   promotion, the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> - one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the
>     corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
> - both types are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of a character type or
>     `void`.

The 'integer promotions' are defined in §6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions.  They're more complex than I want to go through here.

Answer (score 0):

a char is really just an 8 bit number, so a single char alone is no different than an int, except that it can only store smaller numbers. In your printf statement you have

```
%s
```

but a single char is not considered a string, just a number, so you should use

```
%c or %d
```

for you printf statement. If you had an array of chars, then you would use %s

Comment: `char` and `int` are both integer types, but they're still distinct types. This doesn't explain why the message refers to `int` rather than `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

> printf("%c \n", b);

The compiler is casting the char to int on the fly, so the error msg makes sense (at least to someone used to interpreting C compiler messages).

Comment: There is no cast (a cast is an operator written as a type name in parentheses, specifying an explicit conversion). The value of `b` is implicitly *converted* to `int`, for reasons that I explain in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23586407/827263).